# Setting WebRequest's Timeout problem in c# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, webrequest

I'm trying to establish a connection with a FTP server, to achieve this I use `WebRequest.Create()` with some methods ecc ecc.
The problem occurs when the connection can't be established (for example invalid IP address), in fact GetResponse() never returns or returns after a huge amount of time.
I tried to set the Timeout property, but either I did something wrong or there is a bug:

- If I set a number of ms < 16 GetResponse() raises an exception within 100 ms
- If I set a any number of ms > 16 GetResponse() raises an exception after 21 seconds

I found many post with the Timeout problem but nobody highlight or figure out this particular, any ideas?

```
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = cred;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            Logger.Write((DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond).ToString());
            request.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(16).Milliseconds;
            request.GetResponse().Close();
```

EDIT: Well, I made other tests and actually also with 16 ms or less the timeout is quite random.

My goal is to make the `GetResponse()` raise an exception within about 300 msec if the connection is impossible to established.

I also try something like this:

```
 try
 {
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    request.Credentials = cred;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    var task = Task.Run(() => request.GetResponse().Close());
    if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)))
    {
        throw new Exception("Timed out");
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    return false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}
```

With this solution after `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)` an exception is raised and the catch block handle it, but after 21 second the Task launched raise another exception which the catch block doesn't handle.

Comment: The timeout is waiting for the channel to be idle from the time the connection is started.  So there is a time while the connection is completing where channel is idle.  Once connection completes you are getting data continuously and there is no timeout.

Comment: Ok, so the Timeout property is used after the connection has been estabilished. How can i set a timeout for the server to response my connection request?

Comment: Don't use number so small like 16 msec.  Data is not going to be continuous and the timeout should be realistic.

Comment: i set 16 msec just for testing purpose, what i want to achieve is that GetResponse() raises an exception if the connection cannot be established within 300 msec (for example). Is this possible with WebRequest property/method?

Comment: Is the time when > 16ms random like your testing when < 16ms?

Comment: For values higher than 16 msec the timeout expired always after 21 seconds, for values less than 16 it is quite randomic, often after about 100 msec sometime 21 seconds. Anyway, as you explain me, that Timeot property dont fit my need. I'll edit this post for adding more information.

Comment: FTP specification is a subtype of HTTP.  HTTP uses TCP for the transport layer.  TCP is reliable because each datagram gets an ACK.  TCP normally when a ACK isn't received tries up to 3 times at 5 seconds apart.  That would account for 15 seconds and if it is 3 retires after the original attempt than it would be 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to achieve what i was looking for: get an exception if the connection cannot be established within 300 msec.

```
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = cred;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            var task = Task.Run(() => {
                try
                {
                    request.GetResponse().Close();
                }
                catch { }
            });
            if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)))
                throw new Exception("Timed out");
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

This code raises an exception thanks to `task.Wait()`, and, when `request.GetResponse().Close();` returns with an exception (maybe after 21 seconds) it will be handled by the empty internal catch, because actually we have already handled the problem.